# To filter data based on ID list found in other tab using App Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I want to scrape data, but only filter data if Col13 from the data have the IDs listed in another tab. If I hardcode for 1 ID, I managed to do as below:

```
var sid = ss.getSheetByName('sid list').getRange('A2:A').getValues(); //capture list of IDs
        if(temp[13] == 243558369) {

        temp.push(counter)
        // console.log(temp)
        toPrint.push(temp)
        counter++
        }
```

This is the list of IDs to be captured `var sid = ss.getSheetByName('sid list').getRange('A2:A').getValues(); //capture list of IDs`

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `I want to scrape data, but only filter data if Col13 from the data have the IDs listed in another tab.`. And, what is `temp` in your script? And, in your question, `Col13` is used. But, in your script, it seems that you might want to use Col 14 from `temp[13]`. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Hi sorry for the bad question but is already replied and works on my side. Tq! @Tanaike